# Wildcard capture error : why?

Tags: java, generics

I can't understand that wildcard capture error, or found a way to circumvent it:

```
import java.util.List;


class A<B extends A.AA<? extends C>, C> {

  List<C> list;

  public void foo(B inner) {
    C c = get();
    inner.nop(c);
  }

  private C get() {
    return list.get(0);
  }

  static public class AA<D> {
    public void nop(D d) {
        System.out.println(d);
    }
  }
}
```

Here's the javac ouput:

```
Wildcards.java:10: error: method nop in class AA<D> cannot be applied to given types;                
      inner.nop(c);                                                                                
          ^                                                                                       
required: CAP#1                                                                                    
found: C                                                                                           
reason: actual argument C cannot be converted to CAP#1 by method invocation conversion             
where C,D are type-variables:                                                                      
  C extends Object declared in class A                                                             
  D extends Object declared in class AA                                                            
where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:                                                              
  CAP#1 extends C from capture of ? extends C                                                      
1 error
```

Why can't we pass an instance of C to B.nop()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you create an instance of `A` :

```
A<A.AA<String>,Object> a = new A<A.AA<String>,Object>();
A.AA<String> inner = new A.AA<String>();
a.foo(inner);
```

`inner.nop()` should expect a `String`, but you are passing it an `Object`.

One possible fix is :

```
class A<B extends A.AA<C>, C>
```

Comment: OP maybe interested in a solution for rewriting her code.